# How can I change the text of all child widgets inside a parent widget?

Tags: flutter, widget, material-design, flutter-layout

I have a convenience method that returns a `Column` with some `Text` widgets inside it, let's call it `mySpecialColumn(String header, String body)`. Now I have a situation where I want to change the text color in one particular place where I use this method. Since this is a very rare exception, adding a (optional) `Color` parameter to the method signature of `mySpecialColumn` seems overkill.

I found out that I can wrap this instance of my custom widget with `Material`, since it has a `textStyle` property. This seems to work fine, but is this the preferred way to do this?

Perhaps I'm wrong about this, but `Material` seems like it should mainly be used for creating custom `Material` widgets, not something as trivial as changing text color? I would have expected there to be some common widget like `Container` or similar that could alter the text color of it's children?

Comment: possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57624520/5189271

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap `mySpecialColumn` in `Theme` widget. Then use `ThemeData`to set the text color of its children.

```
Theme(
  // Create a unique theme with "ThemeData"
  data: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
        body1: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red
        )
    )
  ),
  child: mySpecialColumn(
        ...
       )
);
```

For more details see [the docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes)

Comment: For a reason unknown to me, this also influenced the `textButtonTheme` of children.

Answer (score 13):

Wrap it with `DefaultTextStyle`, eg:

```
    DefaultTextStyle.merge(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400], fontSize: 12),
        child: Column(...),
    )
```

Answer (score -3):

Something like this?

```
child: Text(
        'Post',
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
```