# How to set color of all text in a specific container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't want to change the text color of the whole app. Just all the text inside a container. Can I wrap it with some other widget or something for this ?

Comment: `DefaultTextStyle`?

Comment: the `Text` widget has a property called `TextStyle` which has a property called `color`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To apply certain `TextStyle` properties only to a subtree of your app. You can use `DefaultTextStyle`

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(
  child: Container(child: /* your subtree */),
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
),
```

as a comment pointed out, this replaces all defaults, not just the color. This can be mitigated by using the `merge` constructor:

```dart
DefaultTextStyle.merge(
  child: Container(child: /* your subtree */),
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
),
```

Comment: Note, this will replace ALL defaults -- not just the color

Comment: Oh my gosh, it was so infuriating trying to get this to work with `Theme`—thank you!

Answer (score 10):

flutter's answer is good in my opinion. But the power of `ThemeData` is more than you think. Here is the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#themes-for-part-of-an-application) about **Themes for part of an application**.

You could provide a `Theme` to wrap your container to provide a new theme. Here is two way to slove it:

### 1. Creating unique ThemeData

```dart
/*Not recommended, this could make a totally different If you just want a little part changed.*/
Theme(
  // Create a unique theme with "ThemeData"
  data: ThemeData(
    textTheme: /* Your Text Theme*/,
  ),
  child: Container(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Your Text Here"),
  ),
);
```

### 2. Extending the parent theme

```dart
Theme(
  // Find and extend the parent theme using "copyWith". See the next
  // section for more info on `Theme.of`.
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(textTheme: /* Provide your theme here! */),
  child: Container(
    child: Text("your text here"),
  ),
);
```

You could also use existed theme with a little changed:

```dart
Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
  body1: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(color: Colors.red),
)
```

Comment: Assuming you just wrap a widget with `Theme`, this doesn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Use `DefaultTextStyle.merge` to keep your theme and just change the color.

```
    DefaultTextStyle.merge(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
        child: Column(...),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `MaterialApp` widget you could use the theme property of it and set different `Text` themes and call them anywhere in your app. For example the following code defines 3 different text themes:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Time Tracker",
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.blue),
          title: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,color: Colors.red),
          body1: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Hind',color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
      ),
      home: LandingPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

You can then call a particular theme(headline) anywhere in your app like this:

`Text('Home Page',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,)`

Which gives you the headline `TextTheme`

Comment: But this applies to the entire app. the user explicitly asked for a solution which only applies to a certain sub tree of their widgets.

Answer (score -2):

I have functions for all my styles

```
TextStyle largeTextStyle() => TextStyle(fontSize: 150);
```

then I just do

```
Text("blah", style:largeTextStyle())
```