# How to set color of all Text widgets under a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57624753/2926992), all I have to do is to wrap a widget with `Theme` and provide `ThemeData`. I return a widget from `build` method as below:

```dart
    Theme( // wrapping `Card` widget with a theme
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith( // extend main theme
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith( // extend main text theme
              subtitle1: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, // subtitle text color to white
              ),
              caption: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, // caption text color to white
              ),
            ),
      ),
      child: Card( // card widget as a child of theme
        // ... other stuff ...
        child: Container(
            margin: _margin,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Text(
                  profile.alias,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1, // set text style to subtitle1
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Joined ${timeago.format(profile.dateJoined)}',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption, // set text style to subtitle2
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Has ${profile.stats.subscriberCount == null ? 0 : profile.stats.subscriberCount} subscribers',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption, // set text style to caption
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Following ${profile.stats.followingCount == null ? 0 : profile.stats.followingCount} people',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption, // set text style to caption
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
```

Oddly, this doesn't affect my text anyway. It still stays black.

[image: texts are black]

Probably there is something I don't understand about the themes. Is there a way to partially apply a theme (in this case, text color) to a widget that affects all direct and *indirect* children?

---

## Environment

- Flutter 2.0.6
- Dart 2.12.3

Comment: where you define theme in your project also define there color for text so when you call theme data its will reflect in your card try this

Comment: Using `Theme()` you have changed the `Theme` of its `child` don't use `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1` again and `Text()` widget uses `bodyText2` theme so instead of using `textTheme.subtitle1` change it to `textTheme.bodyText2` Try like this. Adding property like this `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1` you again setting property of `MaterialApp()` not `Theme()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use `Builder` as a child of `Theme` if you'd like to apply the theme to all children.

---

So, my code above seems to be using the context of `build` method, which is of parent. It changes the theme of the **direct child of `Theme`**. This is quite counter-intuitive but luckily there is a way to initialize a brand new `BuildContext` using `Builder` widget.

So, if you want to apply the theme to all children **whether they are direct or undirect children**, always use `Builder` as a direct child of `Theme`.

```dart
Theme(
  data: // your theme data here
  child: Builder(
    builder: (context) => // this is where you do stuff
  )
)
```

Notice how `Builder` provides a `BuildContext` named `context`? This is a brand new context to work with and actually contains *subtheme* that we have just created rather than the `context` that is provided by `build` method. So, when you create a `Text` widget under `Builder` widgeet somewhere:

```dart
// under Builder widget somewhere
Text(
  'my text',
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption // we have a context here
)
```

The `context` here uses the context provided by `Builder` widget, not the `build` method, which makes it intuitive.

Also, the reason I use `Theme.of` is because *I'd like to extend main theme, not create an empty theme*. And Flutter has many predefined styles for texts such as `bodyText1`, `bodyText2`, `heading1` (up to 6), `caption` etc. and I can use it with this method.

This is, at least, how I have solved the issue and the code makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use the global theme and local theme using `Theme()` to particular widgets.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // Global Theme
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
              bodyText2: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
        cardTheme: CardTheme(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            ),
            color: Colors.blueGrey),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("List Builder"),
        ),
        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(child: Text("Using MaterialApp theme")),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 4,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Theme(
                // Child Theme
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  textTheme: TextTheme(
                    bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                  ),
                  cardTheme: CardTheme(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      // Card Theme of Theme() data
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Hello (Using Theme())",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                      child: Card(
                        // Card Theme of MaterialApp
                        child: Center(
                          child: FittedBox(
                            child: Text(
                              "Welcome(card theme from MaterialApp)",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        shape: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.shape,
                        color: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.color,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Output
[image: Output]

Comment: So, not using `style` property on child `Text` widgets will use the child theme. This is quite counter-intuitive. What if I want to have this *base caption style* and extend it on children? While I was thinking that, something hit my mind. What if I just wrap `Text` widgets with `Builder` widget to provide a new `BuildContext`, which is of the child, thus providing child theme. And it worked actually.

Comment: Yes, it might work that way too. If it works what else I can say.